# i want to count the -ve in a col and put them in another colm using groupby in an col

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

count the number of neg values in delay column using groupby

```
merged_inner['delayed payments']=merged_inner.groupby('Customer Name')['delay'].apply(lambda x: x [x < 0].count())
```

the delayed payments col is showing null

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE]? The code should run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem here is that you are trying to put the results back to the same dataframe as you did `.groupby` with, which won't have `Customer Name` as index.

Consider following minified example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Customer Name':['a', 'b','c','a', 'c','a','b','a'],
    'Delay':[1,     2,  -3,  0,   -1,-2,  -3,2]
})
```

You can even try:

```
df.loc[df['col']<0].groupby('Customer Name')['delay'].size()
```

Output:

```
Customer Name
a          1
b          1
c          2
Name: Delay, dtype: int64
```

You can have  dataframe using:

```
df.loc[df['Delay']<0].groupby('Customer Name')['Delay'].size().reset_index(name='delayed_payment')
```

Output:

```
   Customer Name    delayed_payment
0        a               1
1        b               1
2        c               2
```